# How to maintain session between two sub domain?

Tags: asp.net, subdomain

How to maintain session between sub domains.i tried below its not workout

httpCookies domain=".site.com"

My Folder structure in FTP

site1 > main site a website project.app_code,bin,web.config

```
      Folder Subdomain1. here i have all files like bin,app_code,web.config etc.

      Folder Subdomain2. here also same.
```

Can any one give me an idea how to maintain session between those sub domains.

Answer (score 1):

Use This I hope Its usefull for you.

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)

{

  /// only apply session cookie persistence to requests requiring session information



  #region session cookie

  if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState )

  {

    /// Ensure ASP.NET Session Cookies are accessible throughout the subdomains.



    if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null && Session != null && Session.SessionID != null)

    {

      Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = Session.SessionID;

      Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Domain = ".know24.net"; // the full stop prefix denotes all sub domains

      Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Path = "/"; //default session cookie path root         

    }

  }

  #endregion    

}
```

Comment: Thanks Manish i tried this method how to implement in other domain can you give me details it will helpful for me.

Comment: get value using **string s = Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value;**.

Comment: Thank you manish still i am confusion i put above code in Subdomain1 global.asax file and tried to get the cookie value in Subdomain2 and session in session but its not working.please help me.i m very new to asp.net :-(